# Show only rows from table containing specific word or text

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]
My mysql table structure is given in image. I only want to show the row that matches the text "Palpa" in District Column.

From tablel above the table should only show one row which is second last since it only contains the text "Palpa" in District Column

Here is the code I'm using to display the database rows in table

```
 $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY id DESC");
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM student WHERE district = 'Palpa'`

Comment: This is really simlpe SQL. SO is not intended as a replacement for learning the basics.

Comment: don't cheat doing your homework!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student where district='Palpa' ORDER BY id DESC");
```